# Why was this edit rejected?

Tags: discussion

I suggested an edit for an answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341776/how-to-check-if-a-record-exist-in-a-database-before-inserting-with-php/26341851#comment41347285_26341851), and the suggested edit was rejected because it apparently changes the answer:
[image]

The edit was an attempt to clean up the answer as the user who answered used MySQL and MySQLi code together, and those two cannot be used together because they are completely different APIs.

Why was this suggested edit rejected?

Comment: It wasn't rejected.  A single user voted to reject, but it takes 3 votes to approve or reject in most cases.  I will guess that the user chose to reject because you appear to be changing the answer and not just clarifying issues.

Comment: [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5986047)? It has not been reviewed enough yet.

Comment: Dangit, @psubsee2003 I was in the middle of posting that! heh

Comment: @AndrewBarber I suck at typing too.... so you must really be slow :)

Comment: Careful, it looks like you deleted a `)` on the third IF statement

Comment: Your [other edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5986101) to a different answer on the same question was approved.  But in my opinion, you pushed your luck there.  Adding links to someone else's answer is really not a good idea.  You are effectively putting words in their mouth.

Comment: Giving the active commenting about the issue with mixing APIs here, I am not sure the edit is appropriate. The poster of that answer is *wrong*, but they seem to think they are not. I would let it proceed naturally.

Comment: Interesting. Normally any edit I submit goes through straight away after a single review. Can certain users approve suggested edits and make them live straight away?

Comment: [Improve Edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239157/165773) action allows single reviewer to approve

Comment: @gnat, going to disagree with the duplicate. Original question was about the confusion between a single "reject" vote and the entire edit being rejected. Not how a post should be edited.

Comment: @gnat Would that explain why some suggested edits are 'owned' by another user, when I made the initial edit?

Comment: yes. Actually, if you look closer into [meta-tag:revision-history] of the edited post, you will be able to find out your edit, immediately followed by one made by reviewer

Comment: @gnat, I think you mean [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26341928/revisions)

Comment: right, that's it. In your example, rev 2 is yours, while rev 3 is one made by reviewer

Comment: wrt disagreement with duplicate, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why was this edit rejected?

It has not. In your screenshot it says:

> Your suggested edit is pending review

Not enough people have weighed in on the suggested edit to approve or reject it. It takes 3 "approves" or 3 "rejects" to clear the item. A user can also "approve/reject and edit" to instantly clear the item and add their edit, usually on top of yours.

So you are just confusing a single "reject" vote with "my edit has been rejected". It would show up in [red letters](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5951257) if it was rejected.

Wait and give it some time. The community will get around to it.

---

[The suggested edit has now been rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5986047), however I will not be discussing the reasoning for its rejection. I am only answering the original question.

Comment: Re. "I will not be dissusing [sic] the reasoning for its rejection. I am only answering the original question." Was "Why was this suggested edit rejected?" not the original question, or am I crazy? (Perhaps it was edited into the question during the grace period?)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, the OP was confused between a single "reject" and the whole suggested edit being rejected, as you can see by the screenshot. So I said that it was not rejected; it had not been reviewed enough.

Comment: I get that. But that wasn't the original question. I guess I'm just being pedantic. Of course, your comment about the closing paren being deleted from the `if` statement answers the "why" pretty decisively, I think.